# Access to 5m Terrain data for flood modelling

Tags: data-request, geospatial, uk

I am doing flood modelling for my Parish in Shropshire on a voluntary basis and need high-res elevation data. Terrain 5 from OS would be ideal. Unfortunately I can't get it under the PSMA with OS.

Does anyone know a source of free 5m elevation data. I have tried the Environment Agency Lidar but it's quite noisy and **g**appy.

Ideas please?

Comment: i mean gappy not happy :-)

Comment: Have you tried the universities around there that might have these ?

Comment: I applied to CEDA (Centre for Environmental Data Analysis) who have some promising data but my request was rejected because I was not a registered UK academic.  It seems they will only help if there is a prospect of a paper being published.   Their reply...                                                       "You have recently applied for the Landmap dataset held here at CEDA. Unfortunately, we are unable to grant access as access is only available to UK based academic researchers due to strict licensing and not for personal use."

Answer (score 1):

I googled and it came up here if this is what you were looking for...
https://github.com/openterrain/openterrain/wiki/Terrain-Data

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

If not then you do need to keep google for it. There should be one out there..

By the way, what software are you going to use with it ? If you have ArcGIS, you should be able to find on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The OS Terrain 5 is hi res. The data in the link is much bigger grids and has holes. Im using QGIS which seems OK at this stage. Im a beginner.

Comment: @ John  - ok . what I am trying to say if you have a basemap that has already been provided then maybe find it there...I am not sure for QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

The EU-funded TanDEM X satellite mission has just completed a new global DEM with incredible spatial resolution (30 m/Pixel in xy-direction, 1 m in z Direction)

Currently, the project management have a call open for scientific projects. You can apply for getting data, freely, from anywhere on the globe, given that you are working on a scientific project. (I for one haven't applied yet -cannot give you insider information).

Maybe you can convince them to give you the DEM for your study area. You have to submit a short project description until Dec 01, 2016.

https://tandemx-science.dlr.de/

https://tandemx-science.dlr.de/cgi-bin/wcm.pl?page=investigate_register

Comment: Sorry for late reply knb. I did try a TandemX proposal but was unsuccessful.  The terms are quite onerous regarding reporting and control.  Its run on behalf of the German government.  I have had more luck with CEDA now that I am loosely associated with the University of Reading.  Data is still a tricky area.